# Amadeus GDS itinerary code - What does the code 908 17, 40 , 2 mean?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, gds

In the following Amadeus itinerary What does the code 908 17, 40, 2 mean? Secondly is there any Amadeus document where I can find the list of all such code and its meanings?

```
  2  PG 133 Y 14JUL 1 BKKUSM DK1  1100 1205  14JUL  E  0 319 S                  
     010 AB 4378 /AY 6277 /BA 7965 /EY 7662 /KL 3732 /QF 3494 /QR               
      40                                                                        
     2                                                                          
     908 17                                                                     
     DOM                                                                        
  3  PG 134 Y 19JUL 6 USMBKK DK1  1245 1350  19JUL  E  0 319 S                  
     010 AB 4377 /BA 7960 /BR 3962 /EY 7661 /QR 4007                            
     908 17
```

Comment: Do you have the option to print (`IEP`) or display (`IED`) the itinerary in its extended format? Perhaps that'll give a clue.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can solve half your mystery.  For the first flight, the second row lists codeshares:

```
2  PG 133 Y 14JUL 1 BKKUSM DK1  1100 1205  14JUL  E  0 319 S                  
   010 AB 4378 /AY 6277 /BA 7965 /EY 7662 /KL 3732 /QF 3494 /QR
```

Since flight PG133 is codeshared as QR4012, the `/QR 40 2` bit is almost certainly a typo/copypaste mistake for `/QR 4012`, and you'll note that the second flight lists `/QR 4007` as you'd expect.

No clue about `908 17` though.  I would have guessed it might be a partial ticket number, but that should start with the issuing carrier, and 908 is Voyageur Airways, an obscure Canadian charter outfit.  (Bangkok Airways is 829.)